# Name the paradox which invalidates question when it's answered

Tags: logic, paradox

My friend asked the following and we were unable to figure out the type of paradox it constitutes :

> Name the paradox which means that - if I answer this question, the question will be invalidated.
>
> For example : Could you name 3 things that only you know about yourself.

We looked up on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_paradoxes) without any luck.

Comment: Some form of [performative contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_contradiction) but I'm not too satisfied with this answer myself.

Comment: You could say it's a variation on Russell's barber paradox, but that doesn't really agree with the example. But the rule and the example are not identical (latter is much more specific as a type)

Comment: Explanation about the example - as soon as I tell you what is the thing that only I know, it is no longer the thing which only I know.

Comment: @pat_nafs On second thought: Maybe it _is_ a performative contradiction. It is, if you don't focus on the question but on the answer: "Listen, this is something, only I know about me: ..."

Comment: @Einer - Thanks! Wikilink on performative contradiction lead me to [Self-refuting idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea) - "ideas or statements whose falsehood is a logical consequence of the act or situation of holding them to be true". I think this is what we were looking for. Let me know your thoughts / answer it.

Comment: This example is not a paradox. You can easily answer the question. It is only after that your answer becomes invalid and cannot be used again. Asking a question that requires answers never be repeated is not an example of a paradox.

Comment: I heard a radio ad this morning from some political organization claiming to provide a "voice to the voiceless." But the moment anyone joins, they'd have a voice and they'd no longer be a member!

Comment: Answer: My first secret, my second secret, and the fact that I just killed you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be related to the Berry Paradox.

The Berry Paradox asks : What is the smallest number not nameable in under ten words?

We can answer this by saying "the smallest number not nameable in under ten words".

But by saying that we have expressed this number in under ten words - a contradiction, thus invalidating the question.

**EDIT**

The reason we can answer Berry's question the way we do is due to the well-ordering of the natural numbers.  Every set of natural numbers has a least member.

Comment: ...or then "What is the smallest natural number not nameable in under eleven words"

Comment: @AndrewC Quite right.  I was a bit sloppy in my statement of the paradox.

Answer (score -1):

The Identity Question. 
As a Cretan, I know all Cretans are liars; I swear it is true.

Comment: The identity paradox comes from scripture - "One of themselves, even a prophet of their own, said, The Cretians are alway liars, evil beasts, slow bellies 13 This witness is true..."[Titus 1:12-13]. When the writer testifies "This witness is true" He verifies the paradoxical aspect of true/false veracity.